# Making webapp using Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a big table containing domain data in Google Big query and I would like to create a web app similar to http://whois.domaintools.com/browse/a/

Page with list of sorted results I can dig into.

Is it possible without making query every time page is opened or refreshed which is most ovious way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Querying directly BigQuery introduces lags, which will affect frontend performance, and for some users and queries it will be several seconds, hence it's not recommended to be used on a live website, as the most suitable way is to run asynchronously in the background.

You need to build your website, so the website itself reads the data from a cache or from a local database.

You then need to build a background process (Message Queue or Cron) in which you will periodically run the BigQuery job, and process the results and write to your local database. You can then choose to run only every 1 hour or so.

See what you can do with BigQuery

- https://github.com/everythingme/redash frontend available  at http://demo.redash.io/
- http://bigqueri.es/

Comment: "it's not recommended to be used on a live website" I believe this is true but I'm currently looking for this recommendation and not finding it, other than on third-party blogs...

Comment: @chris even small queries can take 1-2 seconds, if that you accept go for it, otherwise you should use a backend and cache the queries and serve faster

Comment: I agree with you. But I'm looking for official documentation I can link colleagues to.